# Receiving application/octet-stream post with webapi2

Tags: c#, post

I am currently working on a solution where someone is to send XML content to our API over Post.

I am using the below code and it works when the XML-content is delivered with a PHP-script using CURL. When I try the same with a Client using C#, I am not getting the correct XML content out.

Server code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using log4net; 

public class BinaryTextMediaTypeFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{


/// <summary>
///     The _log.
/// </summary>
private readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(BinaryTextMediaTypeFormatter));

/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="BinaryTextMediaTypeFormatter"/> class.
/// </summary>
public BinaryTextMediaTypeFormatter()
{
    this.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));
}

/// <summary>
/// The read from stream async.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="type">
/// The type.
/// </param>
/// <param name="readStream">
/// The read stream.
/// </param>
/// <param name="content">
/// The content.
/// </param>
/// <param name="formatterLogger">
/// The formatter logger.
/// </param>
/// <returns>
/// The <see cref="Task"/>.
/// </returns>
public override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
{
var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
try
{
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    readStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);

    var streamValues = Encoding.Default.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());

    taskCompletionSource.SetResult(streamValues.Trim());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    this.log.Error(e);
    taskCompletionSource.SetException(e);
}

return taskCompletionSource.Task;
}

/// <summary>
/// The can read type.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="type">
/// The type.
/// </param>
/// <returns>
/// The <see cref="bool"/>.
/// </returns>
public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
{
    return type == typeof(string);
}

/// <summary>
/// The can write type.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="type">
/// The type.
/// </param>
/// <returns>
/// The <see cref="bool"/>.
/// </returns>
public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
{
    return false;
}
}
```

Client code (this one has one textbox where you can add your XML, a response-text-box where you print out the response and a send-button):

```
/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Form1"/> class.
/// </summary>
public Form1()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
}

/// <summary>
/// The btn send_ click.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">
/// The sender.
/// </param>
/// <param name="e">
/// The e.
/// </param>
private void BtnSendClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(this.txtContent.Text);
        var postData = GetBytes(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes));

        const string Uri = "http://dev.sportsdata.no/api/Api/FileClient/Odf";

        byte[] response;

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            response = client.UploadData(Uri, "POST", postData);
        }

        this.txtResonse.Text += Environment.NewLine;
        this.txtResonse.Text += @"response: " + response;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        this.txtResonse.Text += Environment.NewLine + @"Starting loop" + Environment.NewLine;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in exception.Data)
        {
            this.txtResonse.Text += @"key: " + kvp.Key + @", value: " + kvp.Value + Environment.NewLine;
        }

        this.txtResonse.Text += @"ending loop" + Environment.NewLine;
        this.txtResonse.Text += @"exception: " + exception.Message + Environment.NewLine + exception.StackTrace;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// The get bytes.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="str">
/// The str.
/// </param>
/// <returns>
/// The <see cref="byte[]"/>.
/// </returns>
private static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    var bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}
```

Some output from the log:

```
This is the content: <2016-02-08 13:35:56,673 [13] ERROR 166ogger [(null)] [(null)] - System.Xml.XmlException: Name cannot begin with the '.' character, hexadecimal value 0x00. Line 1, position 2.
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseQName(Boolean isQName, Int32 startOffset, Int32& colonPos)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
at System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml)
```